# Math operator names with Neo Euler in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, math-operators, unicode-math

I am writing a document in XeLaTeX using Libertine and Neo Euler as fonts:

```
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine G}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Liberation Sans}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Neo Euler}
```

Now when I use operators like `\log` or `\cos`, XeLaTeX typesets them with Neo Euler instead of Libertine (because of the option `math-style=upright`, required for Neo Euler). How can I keep Libertine, or set an other font (for example Liberation Sans, my sans serif font), as the font for operator names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work (I don't have Linux Libertine G, though):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Liberation Sans}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,range=\mathit]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup]{Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{Linux Libertine O Bold}
\begin{document}
log $\log \mathrm{log}\mathbf{log}a+b\sum\int\alpha$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is that alpha coming from? Libertine?

Comment: @sujeet It's from Neo Euler

Comment: I think you will want to set partial=upright, nabla=upright

Comment: @sujeet If one uses `\partial`, surely, because otherwise no symbol appears; I can see no difference with `\nabla`.

Answer (score 2):

As described in [Changing the operator font with unicode-math loaded](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246304/changing-the-operator-font-with-unicode-math-loaded/254225#254225) you can use text font specifically for operators:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Palatino  Linotype}
\setmathfont{Neo Euler}

\setmathfontface\mathOpFont{Palatino Linotype}
\setoperatorfont\mathOpFont
```

I think, this is the most straightforward way, though this interface was introduced years later after the OP's question.