# Changing the operator font with unicode-math loaded

Tags: fonts, math-operators, unicode-math

How could I change the operator font to, let's say, the sans serif style, *with* the `unicode-math` package loaded?

The following code only works without that package:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
\DeclareSymbolFont{sfoperators}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{sfoperators}{bold}{OT1}{cmss}{b}{n}
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\operator@font}{\mathgroup\symsfoperators}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    $\sin x$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the right way to use a sans serif font for operators with the `unicode-math` package is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\operator@font}{\um_switchto_mathsf:}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  $\sin{x}$
\end{document}
```

This will not work unless you use the `unicode-math` package.  Moreover, you'll have to use `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

Answer (score 5):

In the [next version of unicode-math](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/milestones/v0.8) there'll be an interface for this:

```
\setmathfontface\mathfoo{texgyrechorus-mediumitalic.otf}
\setoperatorfont\mathfoo
```

Please speak up if you think there might be a better way to do this `:)`

Answer (score 3):

As of 2021, you can either change the operator font to something other than `\mathrm` with, for example,

```
\setoperatorfont\mathsf
```

or you can change the `\mathrm` font with `\setmathrm`.  If you use `\mathrm` within `\boldmath`, you might also need to `\setboldmathrm`.